# How to add filter to readproperties from file?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In below example, how to ignore the keys in `parameter_file` starting with `_`?

content of `parameter_file`:

```
project=prj/name
_project=bad/prj
_branch=badbranch
branch=mybranch
```

I need to filter out the keys starting with `_` and collect the rest into `fileParams` variable, below collects all the keys available in the `parameter_file` including _project and _branch (these two I need to avoid)

```
props = readProperties file: "parameter_file"
fileParams = props.collect { string(name: it.key, value: it.value) }
build job: "jobName", parameters: fileParams
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
props = readProperties file: "parameter_file"
fileParams = props.findAll{ !it.key.startsWith ('_') }.collect { string(name: it.key, value: it.value) }
```